# QField expression 'current_value()' not working

Tags: qgis, qfield

QField v1.8.4 on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S4 running Android 10.
Project prepared in QGIS 3.14

I have a point layer (trees_pt) - a shapefile. The layer has attributes like inter alia, `spreadN`, `spreadE`, `spreadS`, `spreadW`.

I would like to set `spreadE`, `spreadS`, `spreadW` to default to the current edited value of `spreadN`. I have set the default value for each of `spreadE`, `spreadS`, `spreadW'` to `current_value('SpreadN')`. This seems to have no effect, either in QGIS or QField.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try upgrading to QGIS 3.18 and prepare same project. Seems like there is a bug in QGIS 3.14 and current_value() method.

Comment: O current_value funciona muito bem no QGIS 3.16 e 3.18, mas está derrubando o Qfield 1.9.5